# Forwarding call to Twilio Client

Tags: twilio

I was wondering if it was possible to forward calls, made to a number, to a (Twilio) client.  Similar to forwarding to a number.

So for instance, If someone calls me on +1 XXXXX, it wakes up the (Twilio) client/app on the phone.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.   You simply need to associate a telephone number to TWIML code similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Client>jenny</Client>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

This example right from the TWIML Docs. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client

As for a client waking up, it's dependent upon platform but ways exist to handle on iOS and Android and the JavaScript client implementation is of course dependent upon the browser being connected and nothing more.

Regards,

Jim

Comment: can I pass argument with dial and client Like action url in dial and client url in client? if yes then How?